# Window is not defined (Server-side rendering with Asp.Net SPA Services)

Tags: asp.net, node.js, webpack, server-side-rendering, asp-net-core-spa-services

Thank you guys for reading my question. Really hoping for a solution to this, I've been trying to find a fix for days to no avail.

Here's the rundown: My goal is to render a React application on the server-side using .NET Core. I haven't even started with the react part yet, right now I'm simply trying to render an h1 tag with the ASP.NET Javascript Services Prerendering functionality.

On my first iteration, I wrote my boot-server.js file with es5 and it worked perfectly. However, I quickly realized I was going to need to compile the file through webpack in order for it to understand my React code.

As soon as I piped that file through webpack though, I got a "window is not defined" error which I haven't been able to fix. I understand that part of my application should not be aware of the window object since it lives in the server but setting the webpack config's target field to node does not seem to fix the issue. Below are all the files involved.

Here is my boot-server.js file:

```
import { createServerRenderer } from 'aspnet-prerendering';

module.exports = createServerRenderer((params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var html = '<h1>Hello world!</h1>';
        resolve({
            html: html
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my cshtml view:

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices"

<app id="root" asp-prerender-module="wwwroot/client/boot-server.bundle">Loading...</app>
```

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const path = require("path");

const clientConfig = {
  entry: './FrontEnd/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot/client"),
    filename: "client.min.js",
    publicPath: "/client/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
            plugins: ["transform-class-properties", "transform-decorators-legacy", "react-html-attrs"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "sass-loader"
          }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader?name=[name]_[hash:8].[ext]'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './wwwroot/client',
    hot: true
  }
};

const bootServerConfig = {
  stats: { modules: false },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js'] },
  output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      publicPath: '/wwwroot/client/', // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
  },
  entry: {
    'main-server': './FrontEnd/boot-server.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: /FrontEnd/,
            use: [
                {
                  loader: "babel-loader",
                  options: {
                    presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
                    plugins: ["transform-class-properties", "transform-decorators-legacy", "react-html-attrs"]
                  }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: { limit: 25000 } //?limit=100000'
            }
        }
    ]
    },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './wwwroot/client')
    },
    target: 'node'
}

module.exports = [clientConfig, bootServerConfig];
```

Here is a screenshot of the error page:
[image: Error page]

Comment: `resolve: ({html});` shows no variable named `html` and looks like really odd syntax.  If you were trying to call `resolve()` with the locally defined string as the `html` property of an object, it should be `resolve({html: result});` too.

Comment: You're right. I modified my code a bunch and forgot to put it back like it should be. Still getting the error though.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your ACTUAL code.  We can't guess what code you're running.

Comment: Just edited it.

Comment: which line is throwing the error? You should have got a stack trace, I would have thought

Comment: Just added a screenshot of the error page. I can't seem to get any information out of it since it's bundled (at r ?).